# Hardcoded dropdown (for creating and updating data)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, html-helper

I have this code that:

When you edit the UserProfile (with the corresponding CRUD (Controlers + Views)) you'll see a dropdown for the SexType (that you can also edit with some other CRUD) and will correspond to a SexType table.

```
public class UserProfile{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
public int SexTypeId { get; set; }
public virtual SexType SexType { get; set; }

public class SexType
{
    public int SexTypeId { get; set; }
    public string SexTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

 public class UserProfileDBContext : DbContext //This creates the database according to the model
{
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SexType> SexType { get; set; }
}
```

What I want: 
I want a simpler thing but I can't manage to do it:

I want the sextype to be hardcoded (male / female) on my model (or in the controller). 
Not in a database. 
I don't want any database but just visualize a dropdown with the "male/female" option every time I create or update records on "UserProfile".

Can you help me with that?

Comment: What does your cshtml look like?

Comment: Any reason you ask for sex instead of gender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SexType", 
    new[] { 
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Male", Value = "M" },  
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Female", Value = "F" }
    }
);
```

Comment: You should also add a "Unspecified / Prefer not to tell" option, and probably an "Other" option too.

Comment: I'd include that in the Other category.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new property to your `UserProfile` ViewModel to hold a list ot SexTypes

```
public class UserProfile{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  public int SexTypeId { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SexTypes { get; set; }
}
```

And in your `GET` Action method, you may fill it and return to the View

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model=new UserProfile();
  model.SexTypes = new[]
  {
     new SelectListItem { Value = "M", Text = "Male" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "F", Text = "FeMale" },         
  }; 
  return View(model);
}
```

and in your view which is strongly bounded to `UserProfile` ViewModel,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SexTypeId, new SelectList(Model.SexTypes,
                                                  "Value","Text"), "Select..")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try it out asap. I'm just thinking that I'll have to do some further code for editing the records...